# Github repo with more than one python packages

Tags: python, git, docker, module-packaging

I have created a Github repo in which I keep all the code for my project.

### The structure is:

```
myproject
\
 - package api
 - package database
 - package feature
```

The api package is responsible for communicating with external apis like itunes api.

The database package is responsible for communicating with my database.

Finally the feature package is the actual project i am building.

Each package has its own setup.py.

### I have three problems with this structure:

1. how can i add the dependencies of api and database in the feature setup.py?
2. How would you recommend i deploy this python code in Amazon? Using docker? Platter? Something else?
3. If we assume that more features will be added in the feature as separate packages. How can i deploy only a subset of the code in the server? Lets say package api along with another feature that uses it.

Let me know if my questions are not clear and I will refine them.

Comment: Have you considered splitting it up into three separate Git repos? One for each package - that should make things significantly easier.

Comment: While that is definitely one way to go, I would like to make sure there is no alternative first.

Comment: Please consider splitting this up into multiple questions.